# Is there a way to automatically format code when writing it in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

Is there a way to automatically format code when writing it in PyCharm?

Ctrl-Alt-L can format code one-time, but is there a way to format code as you're writing it?

If not, is there a Python IDE where you can?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `black` with PyCharm and force it to format on each file save, see the official docs https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editor_integration.html